# Bot discord fetch news from API and send message to sever if API response new data

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord BOT that sends news to discord, the data is taken from the API, I want every time the API returns new data, the BOT will send a message to the sever

```
const {
    Client,
    Intents
} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
})
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const moment = require("moment")
const delay = require("delay")

//function fetch news from API
function getNews() {
    return fetch("https://vnwallstreet.com/api/inter/newsFlash/page?important=1&limit=1&start=0&status=-1&uid=-1&time_=1645354313863&sign_=D7CA264A553C671A02DDA0FAA891EE8E")
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            return moment(data.data[0]["createtime"]).format("lll") + " - " + data.data[0]["content"]
            }
        })
}

client.login("TOKEN")

async function main() {
    while (true) {
        client.on("ready", () => {
            client.channels.fetch('944915134315397123')
                .then(channel => {
                    getNews().then(quote => channel.send(quote))
                })
            console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
        })
        await delay(60 * 1000)
    }
}

main()
```

I am facing 2 problems:

- I can't check when the API returns new data because I just want to send new data to the discord channel
- When I use 'delay' once every 1 min in main function, it gives the following error:

```
(node:244) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just listen to the `ready` event every minute. That's gonna cause a memory leak as the warning says.
Make sure the client is ready and fetch the API every 1 minute after that rather than listening to the event again and again, then send the payload to the channel, you don't have to fetch the channel every time either, it's already in the cache.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] })

client.on('ready', async () => {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch('id')
    setInterval(() => {
        fetchDataSomehow().then((data) => {
            channel.send(data)
        })
    }, 60 * 1000)  // runs every 60000ms (60s)
})
```

Comment: I use cron schedule and it's wokr, the second problem solved, but now I want to check if API response new data, I will get this data and send to channel. Do you have any idea?